# Catching httpClient response inside a service with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I have a LoginComponent (form for the credentials) and a LoginService for calling my api with an httpClient.

Usually in my services i'm returning the call so I can subscribe to it inside my component.

For example:

```
doSomething() {
    return this.http.post<any>(...);
}
```

The problem here is that I need to subscribe to the call both inside my component and my service because I want to handle the storage there.

I've found this solution in a tutorial but I think it's not the most appropriate way and maybe there's a better solution using rxjs pipe.

AuthService:

```
login(userName: string, password: string, onSuccess: () => void, onError: (error) => void) {

  this.http.post("https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login", {userName: userName, password: password})
    .subscribe(response => {
      let token = (<any>response).token;
      localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
      this.readUserFromLocalStorage();

      onSuccess();
    }, err => {
      onError(err);
    });
}
```

And inside my component

```
login() {
  this.auth.login(this.userName, this.password,
    () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'),
    (error) => this.invalidLogin = true
  );
}
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt, why roll your own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your auth service you could use a `tap` inside a `pipe`.

A `tap` is a really good way to do something with the response without modifying it. (If you do need to modify it on the way to your component then you should probably use a `map` function.

```js
  this.http.post("https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login", {userName: userName, password: password})
    .pipe(tap(response => {
      let token = (<any>response).token;
      localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
      this.readUserFromLocalStorage();
     }));
}
```

Then you could subscribe in your component.

```
login() {
  this.auth.login(this.userName, this.password).subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  },
    (error) => this.invalidLogin = true
}
```

This way you don't need to have a callback to your service! Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks James !

Comment: Amazing! Glad I could help. If you could accept it as the best answer then that would be awesome :)